# Apache Spark: Running jobs in parallel in standalone mode

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, kinetica

We are trying to get data from an Oracle database into Kinetica database through Apache Spark.

We installed Spark in standalone mode. We executed the following commands. However, we have tried everything but we couldnt manage to run jobs in parallel. We use 2 IBM servers each of which has 128cores and 1TB memory.

We also added  in the spark-defaults.conf  :

```
spark.executor.memory=64g
spark.executor.cores=32
spark.default.parallelism=32
spark.cores.max=64
spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR
spark.sql.shuffle.partions=32
```

On the machine: 10.20.10.228

```
./start-master.sh --webui-port 8585

./start-slave.sh --webui-port 8586 spark://10.20.10.228:7077
```

On the machine 10.20.10.229:

```
./start-slave.sh --webui-port 8586 spark://10.20.10.228:7077
```

On the machine: 10.20.10.228:

We start the Spark shell:

```
spark-shell --master spark://10.20.10.228:7077
```

Then we make configurations:

```
val df  = spark.read.format("jdbc").option    
("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://10.20.10.148:1433;databaseName=testdb").option
("dbtable", "dbo.temp_muh_hareket").option("user", "gpudb").option   
("password", "Kinetica2017!").load()

import com.kinetica.spark._
val lp = new LoaderParams("http://10.20.10.228:9191", "jdbc:simba://10.20.10.228:9292;ParentSet=MASTE
R", "muh_hareket_20", 
false,"",100000,true,true,"admin","Kinetica2017!",4, true, true, 1)  
SparkKineticaLoader.KineticaWriter(df,lp);
```

The above commands successfully work. The data transfer completes. However, jobs work serially not in parallel. Also executors work serially and take turns. They dont work in parallel.

How can we make jobs work in parallel?

I really appreciate your help. We have done everything that we could.